# javascript validate allows submit even if there an error

Tags: javascript

I have HTML form with javascript validation but whenever i submit the form error message appear even if the form fields are correct(not empty or null)

I want the error message to appear only when form fields are empty or null when i submit the form

```
<html lang="en-US">
      <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0.1,shrink-to-fit=no">
         <link type="text/css" href="/css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
           <title>Javascript Form Validation</title>
            <style>
             </style>
              </head>
               <body>
                <div class="container">
                 <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                   <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">

    <form method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName1">Full name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputName1" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div> 
    <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
      class User
                {
                    constructor(userName,submitButton)
                    {
                        this.userName = document.myForm.name.value;
                        this.submitButton = document.getElementById("myForm");
                    }
                    submitForm()
                    {
                        this.submitButton.onsubmit = function()
                        {

                        if(this.userName == "" || this.userName == null)
                        {
                            document.write("Name Required");
                            return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                let user = new User();
                user.submitForm();
    </script>
```

Comment: Consider using `preventDefault`?

Comment: yeah but no success

Comment: I use it to success all the time. What makes yours different? Care to share the code in the question?

Comment: This code is not consistent, the handling of event onsubmit in a method will not tear it apart

Comment: Mr evolutionxbox  can u show me how to use the solution you suggested above? Then Mister Jojo what can we do to get the expected outputs

Comment: you also can't get values before submit, + it's more easy to use names than Id

Comment: Mister Jojo can u please use Object Oriented ? To get same results

Comment: I made it with a **Class** obect , my first answer is already in object oriented, this JS = a object oriented langage

Comment: did you see my updated answer ?????

Comment: You're getting the value from input at page load, but you need to get it when form is submitted, just declare that variable and get its value inside `submitForm()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prefer to code this way:

```
<form method="post" id="my-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName1">Full name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
            name="userName" 
            aria-describedby="nameHelp"
            placeholder="Enter name" >
  </div> 
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

```
const myForm = document.getElementById("my-form")

myForm.onsubmit=event=>
  {
  if(myForm.userName.value.trim()==='')
    {
    event.preventDefault()
    alert("Name Required")
    }
  }
```

or, with a JS class  (in HTML / JS everything is allready OBJECT, even a form)

```
class User {
  constructor(formID,uName) {
    this.myForm = document.getElementById(formID)
    this.u_Name = this.myForm[uName]

    // this.myForm.onsubmit = e => this.doSubmit(e)
    this.myForm.addEventListener('submit', this.doSubmit.bind(this))
  }
  doSubmit(e) {
    if(this.u_Name.value.trim()==='') {
      e.preventDefault()
      alert("Name Required")
    }
  }
};

let user = new User('my-form','userName');
```

```js
class User {
  constructor(formID,uName) {
    this.myForm = document.getElementById(formID)
    this.u_Name = this.myForm[uName]

    // this.myForm.onsubmit = e => this.doSubmit(e)
    this.myForm.addEventListener('submit', this.doSubmit.bind(this))
  }
  doSubmit(e) {
    if(this.u_Name.value.trim()==='') {
      e.preventDefault()
      alert("Name Required")
    }
  }
};

let f_User = new User('my-form','userName')
```

```html
<form method="post" id="my-form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName1">Full name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" 
            name="userName" 
            aria-describedby="nameHelp"
            placeholder="Enter name" >
  </div> 
  <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Hello Mister Jojo Sorry for the delayed response. . i see what you did ,,,,,everything works perfectly

Comment: @ Mister Jojo is this arrow function  this.myForm.onsubmit = e => this.doSubmit(e)  Same as      doSubmit()
    {
  this.myForm.onsubmit = function(e)
  {
   return e;

Comment: alternative to arrow function

Comment: Thank you Share your contacts please

Comment: Please @ Mister Jojo email me at www.justinwilliam@gmail.com

Comment: @GoodnessGoodnessChi why should I do that?

Comment: @ Mister Jojo ts all about Programming