# Unable to Submit HTML form Validated With Javascript Class

Tags: javascript, html, class, variables

i'm new to programming especially JS i have an HTML FORM validated With JS CLASS the problem comes after fill out all required fields correctly but when i click the submit button i am getting the error message that prevent form from being submitted !

since my code not work as it was intended what mistake i made there?

how do i validate and submit a form using JS CLASS? (object oriented javascript)

```html
<html lang="en-US">
      <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=0.1,shrink-to-fit=no">
         <link type="text/css" href="/css" rel="stylesheet">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
           <title>Javascript Form Validation</title>
            <style>
             </style>
              </head>
               <body>
                <div class="container">
                 <div class="row justify-content-center">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                   <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">

    <form method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputName1">Full name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputName1" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div> 
    <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <script>
      class User
                {
                    constructor(userName,submitButton)
                    {
                        this.userName = document.myForm.name.value;
                        this.submitButton = document.getElementById("myForm");
                    }
                    submitForm()
                    {
                        this.submitButton.onsubmit = function()
                        {

                        if(this.userName == "" || this.userName == null)
                        {
                           alert("Name Required");
                            return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                let user = new User();
                user.submitForm();
    </script>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javascript validate allows submit even if there an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59806157/javascript-validate-allows-submit-even-if-there-an-error)

Comment: nope @Sashi....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because at the time you create the user object the name IS empty.

You're only setting it in the constructor. You need to get the value when submit is clicked.

One option is changing it as follows:

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" id="myForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleInputName1">Full name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="exampleInputName1" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Enter name">
    </div> 
    <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
<script>
    class User
    {
        constructor(userName,submitButton)
        {
            this.userName = document.myForm.name.value;
            this.submitButton = document.getElementById("myForm");
        }
        submitForm()
        {
            this.submitButton.onsubmit = function()
            {
                this.userName = document.myForm.name.value;  // <---- Here we reset userName to the input/s current value
                if(this.userName == "" || this.userName == null)
                {
                    alert("Name Required");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    let user = new User();
    user.submitForm();
</script>
```

We re-set the userName in the submit handler

Comment: what are the princples of writting Javascript code?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the initial value of the "name" input in your constructor, with this code:

```
this.userName = document.myForm.name.value;
```

The `userName` property of your class now holds that initial value, which is empty. When you check the value in your `onSubmit` function, the `userName` property is still empty.

What you need to do is get the current value of the input in your `onSubmit` handler. Something like this:

```
this.userName = document.myForm.name.value;
if (this.userName == "" || this.userName == null)
{
    alert("Name Required");
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not work because you are inizializing userName in the constructor when the input is empty and when you are checking userName value it is still empty.
You have to fill the userName with the input value before the check.

Something like:

```
class User
{
    constructor(userName,submitButton)
    {
        this.userName = document.myForm.name.value;
        this.submitButton = document.getElementById("myForm");
    }

    submitForm()
    {
        this.submitButton.onsubmit = function()
        {
            this.userName = document.myForm.name.value;

            if(this.userName == "" || this.userName == null)
            {
                alert("Name Required");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

let user = new User();
user.submitForm();
```

I advise you to create a method to read the userName property because it is 
redundant

Comment: what do you mean from your advice ? explain to me practically